# writing a game server?

Tags: sockets, serversocket, mmo

I want to write an mmo game server, but I can't seem to find any links that will tell me where to start off. Do I have to have my own server? Could I make a game server using GoDaddy as a host? Any information is a help.

I've made demo games with a server/client on LAN, and I am comfortable enough with network programming. My issue is making an online server. I just don't know where to start.

Comment: This is not going to be what you want to hear, but you need to learn to program before you can even begin to make an MMO, especially if you mean one with a graphical client and not just a text MUD or something.

Comment: I assume that **ddan** is expert in programming, but has no ideas about servers :)

Comment: Well, to be more specific, you need to become very comfortable with network code before writing a game server.  Specifically, look into sockets in whatever your language of choice is.  With such a vague question, it's hard to be more specific than that without going way overboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are to buy server, where you server-side game will run. Goddady the cheapest solution is virtual dedicated server...

Comment: thank you... any links for writing the server?

Comment: I like idea of **NeeL** - try to create local server. What programming platform do you want to program?

Comment: I would prefer to use C++. Right now I'm messing around with PHP sockets.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, give a look at what is network-programming, try to create an echo server or a little chat and test all of this locally before buying anything.
That's my advice.

Comment: I've made demo games with a server/client on LAN, but I need to know how to get started making an online server to handle the load.

Comment: You can try hosting on your PC to begin ? It can handle like 10-20 players easy if you have a descent connection.